# Mapping between FDIR to RSS queues for Intel 82599ES

Tags: linux-kernel, drivers, ethernet, intel

I am working with Intel 82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ NIC with linux 4.4.0-116-generic native ixgbe driver. I am wondering about flow indirection table coming with NIC which has 16 fdir queues.

Those queues can be reflected as output of command

```
sudo ethtool -x enp2s0f1

RX flow hash indirection table for enp2s0f1 with 40 RX ring(s):
    0:      0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7
    8:      8     9    10    11    12    13    14    15
   16:      0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7
   24:      8     9    10    11    12    13    14    15
   32:      0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7
   40:      8     9    10    11    12    13    14    15
   48:      0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7
   56:      8     9    10    11    12    13    14    15
   64:      0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7
   72:      8     9    10    11    12    13    14    15
   80:      0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7
   88:      8     9    10    11    12    13    14    15
   96:      0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7
  104:      8     9    10    11    12    13    14    15
  112:      0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7
  120:      8     9    10    11    12    13    14    15
RSS hash key:
98:66:ff:44:ee:dd:32:dd:16:d3:e3:c0:16:b7:0d:11:1c:3d:e3:a6:1d:f1:44:14:36:8d:32:b1:4a:75:ae:d8:f2:97:7c:aa:7c:4c:9e:fb
```

So based on hash, incoming traffic gets divided into 16 fdir queues but later it gets mapped into 40 ring buffers aka RSS queues.

I can tweak fdir queues with various `ethtool -X` commands for its processing weight. At the same time, with help of `/proc/irq/IRQ_NUMBER/smp_affinity` we can control scheduling of RSS interrupts to particular CPUs.

But I am not able to figure out, how traffic maps between fdir queues to rss queues when their count mismatch.

Thanks in advance for help.